# Back-forecasting in MA(2) model

Tags: time-series, self-study, forecasting, arima, moving-average

> The sales of a certain product are represented by the model 
>   $$Z_t=3+a_t+0.5a_{t-1}-0.25a_{t-2}$$ where $a_t\sim WN(0,4)$ (White 
>   Noise).
>
> Given the data $Z_1=3.25,Z_2=4.75,Z_3=2.25$ and $Z_4=1.75$.  Find
>   $\hat{Z}_4(l)$ for $l=1,2,3,100$.

This is an $MA(2)$ model with nonzero mean. The MMSE forecast expression that I founded are
$$\hat{Z}_t(1)=3+0.5a_t-0.25a_{t-1}$$
$$\hat{Z}_t(2)=3+0.5a_t$$
$$\hat{Z}_t(l)=3\quad l\geq 3$$

So the question that came to my mind is, how will I calculate this if I do not know the values of $a_t$?

I need to assume that the initial values of $ a_t $ are zero?

**EDIT:** I was reading something about back-forecasting to estimate the values of $a_t$ and then the forecasts, but I don't understood well how to apply it. Is this the way?